# Ошибка после установки VQmod на Opencart

Tags: php

Установил VQmod на Opencart. Все делал по инструкции. Вылетело сообщение о успешной установке. Но при загрузке сайта, выскакивает ошибка

> ERROR - YOU NEED DOMDocument INSTALLED TO USE VQMod

Что с ней сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно у вашего хостинга не хватает расширения для php:
php5-xml

Answer (score 0):

ERROR - YOU NEED DOMDocument INSTALLED TO USE VQMod   переведится - ОШИБКА - вы должны устнановить DOMDocument для использования VQMod

гляньте [тут](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/Ошибка-fatal-error-class-domdocument-not-found.46041/)